# Automatic IP assignment in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to automatically assign an IP address to a Windows Phone programatically. I can think of two possible approaches
1. assign a private IP address
2. use DHCP client in AutoIP mode

is this even possible?i cannot find a solution to any of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

None of those are possible. You have no control over IP assignment on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, you cannot play with IP addresses (neither getting nor setting) in Windows phone 7.0 and 7.5.

I also tried for a long time but finally I gave up and turned to android...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you find out the MAC address of your WP7 and then set up a DHCP reservation at a particular IP for that MAC address (I've done this on my little home WiFi router). 
Apparantly there is no way to determine the MAC address through the phone itself; you'll have to find it off the network itself.

Comment: thanx alot but i only have an access point to connect to and there is no DHCP server.